# How to install an OSX Automator workflow using „Packages“ installer

Tags: macos, installation, automator

I want to use the OSX „*Packages*“ installer to install an *Automator* workflow, which uses an *Obj-C Automator action*.
The workflow had to be installed in the folder „*Services*", and the Obj-C action in the folder „*Automator*“, both in the user’s or system library.
Unfortunately, *Packages* shows only part of the existing file hierarchy:

Finder window:
[image]

Packages window:
[image]
Particularly *Packages* does not show the *Automator* folder, so that I cannot create the required payload.

In the [docs](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/resources.html) I could not find a way to get access to the hidden folders.

Any suggestion how to create such an installer package is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install something in the `Library/Automator` folder (and others that already exist or not), one has to do the following:

1. Activate in the Contents pane the `Library` line
2. Use the menu command `Hierarchy/New Folder`. This adds a new folder to `Library` in the Contents pane.
3. Rename it `Automator`.
4. Activate the new `Automator` line.
5. Use the + button to add a payload to the `Automator` folder.

Please note that **the created installer will install the payload in an existing `Automator` folder. It will not replace an existing Automator folder with a new folder!**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `Packages` is correctly trying to prevent you from installing something into `/System/Library`.  In general, the contents of `/System/Library` is part of OS X itself and is managed by Apple.  The correct place for user-installed system-wide items is in `/Library`.

Comment: To my understanding, Packages installes by default not is the current user's home /Library, but in the systems /Library. To install in the user's home directory requires a special setup <http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/Q&A_3.html>. But even then I do not have access to the Automator folder.

Comment: I'm not talking about the user's home library, `/Users/xxx/Library`.  I'm talking about the system-wide library for third-party items, `/Library`.  In general, you should never install things into `/System/Library`; that's what `/Library` is for.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Anyway, the Automator folder apparently cannot be accessed there either.

Comment: Did you try manually creating an `/Library/Automator` folder on your system?  (See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/HowAutomatorWorks.html)

Comment: This folder exists already, and contains e.g. a lot of Microsoft Office Automator actions.

Comment: One last suggestion: can you use the `+` button shown at the bottom of the `Packages` window above to add the `/Library/Automator` folder to the display?  Otherwise, you could perhaps use a folder that does exist and then manually alter the package script output.  Good luck!

Comment: The + button only allows to select a payload that will be installed in a selected folder. But due to your suggestions (thanks a lot!!), I found the right solution, and I will post my answer in a minute, so that it may help others.